# python regex match a group or not match it

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the string:

> from string as string

It may or may not contain `as`.

The current code I have is

```
r'(?ix) from [a-z0-9_]+ [as ]* [a-z0-9_]+'
```

But this code matches a single `a` or `s`. So something like `from string a little` will also be in the result.

I wonder what is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: could it be `from string string string as number`?

Comment: What about `from string something`?

Comment: Thanks for reformating my question @ctwheels , I didn't know how to insert inline code like `this`. Hi @RomanPerekhrest, no, there can only be one `string` between `from` and `as`, if there is `as` otherwise it will just be `from string string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)from\s+[a-z0-9_]+\s+(?:as\s+)?[a-z0-9_]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oyjmYo/1)

Note that you use `x` "verbose" (free spacing) modifier, and all spaces in your pattern became formatting whitespaces that the `re` engine omits when parsing the pattern. Thus, I suggest using `\s+` to match 1 or more whitespaces. If you really want to use single regular spaces, just omit the `x` modifier and use the regular space. If you need the `x` modifier to insert comments, escape the regular spaces:

```
r'(?ix) from\ [a-z0-9_]+\ (?:as\ )?[a-z0-9_]+'
```

Also, to match a sequence of chars, you need to use a *grouping* construct rather than a character class. Here, `(?:as\s+)?` defines an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of `as` + space substring.

Comment: This saves my day @Wiktor Stribiżew.  maybe `[ ]`, that is a space inside square bracket, is the same as `\  `, that is back slash followed by a space. What about `[ ]+` and `\ +`? Are they the same?

Comment: @piA2: Whitespaces inside character classes are treated as meaningful chars by Python `re` (unlike Java regex library).  See [this demo](https://ideone.com/gLN86D). So, `[ ]+` and ``\ +`` are equal in Python `re`.